# Redux: importing selectors into actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

There seems to be agreement that if an action creator needs state information (and we want to be independent of state shape), the component calling the action should submit the required state slices to the action. See e.g. Dan Abramov's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35297498/1827442)

But why are we not instead importing selectors into actions?

```
import { mySelector } from '../reducers';

const myAction = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const requiredState = mySelector(getState());
  etc...
};
```

It looks like this would save at least some state slices a roundtrip through components and de-couple things.

What's the disadvantage of doing this? (Except perhaps that actions cannot export `ActionTypes`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if you *are* going to access the store state in your action creators, thunks, or sagas, then you *should* use selector functions to encapsulate the lookup process.

The other aspect of your question is *if* accessing the store state in an action creator is a good idea.  Dan has some reservations about it, and I understand where he's coming from, but from my point of view it's fine.  I wrote a blog post that discusses a number of common concerns about use of thunks, sagas, and state called [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/), and gave my reasons why I feel that those concerns are not generally real problems to worry about.

Comment: Tons of helpful thoughts at the core of the question in your link. Voting up as much as I can :)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the idea in the comment you mentioned is to "decouple" your action from state.

Decoupling the actions from the application state taking in the data you need from where the actions are called make the actions not bounded to state.

Usually decoupling is always a good thing, some advantages:

- Easier to maintain code and change implementations
- Easier unit test.
- Less dependencies for your actions.

Comment: However with that, aren't we just tightly coupling actions to component logic instead? Now every different component using the action needs to provide the correct, sometimes identical, state slice. Isn't that more brittle and coupling than keeping the dependency on the "data layer" with selectors?

Comment: @bebbi The application could use "container", the container will dispatch the action not directly the component. IMO this works quite well with stateless component in React.

Comment: @bebbi the component could neither be bounded to application state nor to state logic. The component just display data and react to user input/event and delegate accessing state and application logic to the container. The container execute logic and dispatch action so the reducer can change the state.

Comment: thanks @GibboK. Yes, I was referring to containers earlier. So, in the example of action requiring a fixed state slice, you are suggesting a single container with the necessary selector and hook it up with multiple presentational components whenever that action is needed?